# Set data-attribute if contains image as child

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, jquery-data

To get my lightbox working, I am trying to set the data attribute "lightbox" on links that contain an image as a child. This doesn't seem to work too well. I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8cew/).

```
var links = $(".single .entry-content a");
links.each(function () {
    if ($(this).children("img").length > 0) {
        $(this).data("lightbox","image-gallery");
        console.log("test");
    }
});
```

The console logs, but the data-attribute isn't set. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(".single .entry-content a:has(> img)").attr('data-lightbox', 'image-gallery')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nm5Ak/)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/has/ -- worth noting that setting the `data-` attribute is technically different than using the `.data()` setter method, and why. In older versions of jQuery the `.data()` properties were set once when the DOM was loaded, and adding a `data-` attribute later on wouldn't alter the `.data()`. That's no longer true in current versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `.data()` function does not add data attributes, but instead uses it's own internal storage mechanism. To actually change the attribute, you'll need to use `attr()`:

```
$('.single .entry-content a').has('> img').attr('data-lightbox', 'image-gallery');
```

Comment: +1 from me too.  It irks me when people can't be bothered to explain things.